# Is "family descent" a legitimate nuance of מוֹצָאָה (môtsâ'âh) in Micah 5:2, as Strong's Concordance seems to indicate?

Tags: hebrew, definition, micah

The word מוֹצָאָה (môtsâ'âh) appears only twice in the OT (KJV).  The first time it appears it is rendered draught house, which is to say latrine or privy:

> And they brake down the image of Baal, and brake down the house of Baal, and made it a **draught house** unto this day. - 2 Kings 10:27

And the second time it appears it is rendered going forth/coming forth/origin:

> But thou, Bethlehem Ephratah, though thou be little among the thousands of Judah, yet out of thee shall he come forth unto me that is to be ruler in Israel; whose **goings forth** have been from of old, from everlasting. - Micah 5:2

Strong's concordance defines this word, ascribed as H4163, as:

> מוֹצָאָה môwtsâʼâh, mo-tsaw-aw'; feminine of H4161; (marg.; compare H6675) **a family descent**; also a sewer:—draught house; going forth.

Brown-Driver-Briggs does not, however, seem to indicate anything that sounds like family descent.

From where does Strong's definition acquire this nuance of family descent and does it rightly color the meaning of this word?

Comment: Are these two meanings the same - "going forth" is what happens in a latrine.

Comment: @Dottard They could be although "pushed out in a latrine" would read awkwardly in Micah.  I'm more interested in the nuance of family descent.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is quite simple. Both terms shown (the first a noun, the second a verbal form) in the two passages you quote (2 Kin 10:27 and Mic 5:2 [1]) derived **from the same Hebrew conceptual root**, namely יצא, with the meaning of '**to go forth, go out**', applied to the 'productions' of the earth, as well as, to those of humankind (namely, children), and so on (including organic human waste, as in 2 Kin 10:27).

Strong's Lexicon itself shows this derivation chain: H2218 (יצא) > H4161 > H4163.

If you need of further references, I list here some of them:
**Davidson**'s Lexicon, p. 475. 1st col., under מוצאתי; p. 336 2nd col. under יצא; **Parkhurst**'s Lexicon, under יצא (he quoted here the passage of Mic 5:2 [1], on the point '1.'); **Schoekel**'s Dictionary, p. 351 (Ital. edit.), under יצא (point '2.'); *The Dictionary of Classical Hebrew*, vol. 4, p. 257, 1st col., under יצא (§ 'Subj. not specified'); **Mandelkern**'s Concordance, p. 496, 3rd col., under 'צא 3 impf.'.

I hope these notes will help you.